# My OS claims there is already a folder in %localappdata%, how do I find it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-folders

To begin with I have to delete a folder name `specific` (just a placeholder) from my `user/%localappdata%` folder to replace it with another one. However that folder is nowhere to be found. So the next logical step is to create an empty one with the exact same name...

After trying for so long my OS (Windows 7, 64bit) won't let me create one cause it claims there is one at the destination already, and only let's me merge the contents of my newly created folder with the one already existing. If I choose to accept the newly created folder is immediately removed. However I can't view nor access the "original" folder that's supposed to be there and it's nowhere to be found.

Please note that I have the "Show hidden files and folders" checked. How do I workaround that? Why is this happening? Is localappdata connected to another folder somewhere?

Comment: the address isn't `user/%localappdata%` it's just `%localappdata%` Try typing that in the Start/search instead

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous: do you want to *find* the directory or *delete* it?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Un**check "Hide protected operating system files".

and/or

2. Go into Command Prompt (`cmd`). 
   `cd` to `%localappdata%` and do `dir /a`.